# Unable to install ffmpeg on CircleCi 2.0

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, debian, ubuntu-14.04

I have `Ruby on Rails` project which uses CircleCi to run tests. In the past I was using CircleCi 1.0 but now I migrated to CircleCi 2.0. I have problem with installing ffmpeg. CircleCi 2.0 uses Ubuntu 14.04. I install ffmpeg like this:

```
# ffmpeg installation
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

and my `circle.yml` config file looks like this:

```
version: 2
environment:
  TZ: "/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Los_Angeles"

jobs:
  build:
    parallelism: 2
    working_directory: ~/circleci-survey-builder
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1-node
        environment:
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
          PGUSER: ubuntu
          RAILS_ENV: test
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: ubuntu
          POSTGRES_DB: circle_test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ''
    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: 'Install CircleCI dependencies'
          command: bash deploy/circle-dependencies.sh

      - type: cache-restore
        key: dashboard-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

      - run:
          name: 'Install gems'
          command: bundle install --path vendor/bundle

      - type: cache-save
        key: dashboard-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        paths:
          - vendor/bundle

      - run:
          name: 'Install postgresql-client'
          command: sudo apt install postgresql-client

      - run:
          name: 'Create database.yml'
          command: mv config/database.ci.yml config/database.yml

      - run:
          name: Set up SurveyBuilder database
          command: bundle exec rake db:structure:load --trace

      - run:
          name: 'Run tests'
          command: |
            bundle exec rspec spec
```

It returns following error when I run build on CircleCi:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
bash deploy/circle-dependencies.sh

Fetching: bundler-1.16.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0
1 gem installed
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found


Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease

Get:1 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]

10% [1 InRelease 13.8 kB/145 kB 10%] [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to securHit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg

Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release

Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.2 kB]

Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9063 kB]

Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]

Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [610 kB]

100% [3 Packages 9063 kB]100% [3 Packages 9063 kB]Fetched 9904 kB in 1s (8178 kB/s)

Reading package lists... 1%
Reading package lists... 61%
Reading package lists... Done


Reading package lists... 1%
Reading package lists... Done


Building dependency tree... 0%
Building dependency tree       


Reading state information... Done

Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
Exited with code 100
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: it seem's you got error like "sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found". 
Try to install special package 'apt-get install software-properties-common'

Comment: I've added that to my build but problem is still the same.

Comment: Oh that's bad. Found couple of solution, just check the below link. https://superuser.com/questions/286675/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-debian.

Comment: Can you add `cat /etc/os-release` and see what info you get?

Comment: @TarunLalwani:

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Comment: @MateuszUrbański Does CircleCi directly use the `ffmpeg` binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the system is now Debian 8.0 (jessie) and not Ubuntu 14.04. You need to enable backports

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
apt update
apt install -y ffmpeg
```

Comment: This gaves mi following error:

```Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
Exited with code 100```

Comment: Also I think that adding backports failed: ```deploy/circle-dependencies.sh: line 5: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied```

I've tried with sudo but the result is the same.

Comment: Need to check if circle ci allows adding repos