# ERROR while Installing FFMPEG through Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I am trying to install ffmpeg in dockerfile.
For that, I am using following this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879064/failed-to-fetch-http-ppa-launchpad-net) . Please, have look at the link before answering. 
Following the answer given to that link, I am using these commands,,,

> RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
>
> RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
>
> RUN apt-get update
>
> RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg   RUN apt-get install -y frei0r-plugins

After successfully executing first two commands, **apt-get update** fails miserably.

> Hit://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
>
> Err://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages    Get:3
>   ://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [589 kB]
>
> Hit://deb.debian.org jessie Release
>
> Err://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages    Err
>   ://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages    Get:4
>   ://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [23.0 kB]
>
> Err://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages    Get:5
>   http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
>
> Err ://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
>
> 404  Not Found
>
> Fetched 9900 kB in 8s (1161 kB/s)
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

And I understood the reason that [why it fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879064/failed-to-fetch-http-ppa-launchpad-net) .

I would have certainly followed the solution given in the above link. Since I am working on docker. I can't do much. is there any other way to install FFMPEG on docker with all it's tools and functionalities ?

Moreover, I wasn't able to post the acutal content of the error, due to constrain that " I can't post more than 8 links , since my ratings are low." .
so in the error log, there is '`http`' , before '`://`'.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205298/unable-to-install-ffmpeg-on-circleci-2-0/47327172#47327172, you are not using debian related repo

Comment: @TarunLalwani , I didn't get what u mean :( . I guess, I am using node:8 as base image. and that's Debian.

Comment: I meant `ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` is not for debian I believe

Comment: ohhkay. but is there anyway I can install ffmpeg on debian :(  ?

Comment: That's what the link was for, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205298/unable-to-install-ffmpeg-on-circleci-2-0/47327172#47327172, follow the steps given in same

Comment: why not alpine? i have docker file with ffmpeg in alpine

Comment: @Adiii can u pls send me link ?

Comment: https://github.com/Adiii717/alpine_nodejs_dockerfile

Comment: @TarunLalwani , thanks a lot. Just now installation worked. but seems like, all the tools are not installed. like 'ffprob', which I clearly need to get the dimensions of the video. Is there any easier way to install all the tools and functionalities ?

Comment: Try adding `apt-get install libav-tools` and see what happens